# How to conduct Phylogenetic Principal Component Analysis (pPCA) using tree with no branch lengths in R?

Tags: r, pca, phylogeny

I'd like to carry out a phylogenetic comparative modeling, for which I have to use predictors that are substantially correlated with one another. I'd like to apply phylogenetic principal component analysis (pPCA) of the package 'phytools' on the predictors - however, it is not allowed to use a phylogenetic tree that has no branch lengths. The problem is that the number of species in my data is quite large (thousands), and the trees I was able to obtain come from supertree analyses and consensus trees, containing no branch lengths.

My question would be: how can I perform pPCA on my data, using phylogenetic trees with no branch lengths, using R? Or what alternative approaches might be applied, to solve to collinearity in my predictors, while also controlling for the phylogenetic relationships between taxa?

Cheers,

Zoltan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have the choice to assign arbitrary branch lengths to the tree. Such as, each length equals 1 (or any arbitrary constant) or branch lengths are proportional to the number of tips. You can use compute.brlen function from ape.

Comment: Thank you, somewhat later I found compute.brlen and used Grafen's method, and it's working perfectly.